# Segmentation Fault 11 caused by buffer?

Tags: python

I've been pulling my hair out because of this forever. I'm new to the C language. It keeps giving me a "Segmentation fault: 11" error message. I can't figure out what's wrong.

I think the problem may lie with the following segment of my code:

```
int counter = 21; 


 char load[counter];


while(fgets(load, 81, input) != NULL)
```

Comment: Maybe allocating `buffer[21]` isn't the right thing to do when you end up doing `fgets(buffer, 81, input)`?

Comment: Seriously? Allocate a buffer that's big enough! What did you expect, "do a barrel roll"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a memory access problem. You have:

```
int B = 21;

...

char buffer[B];

...

while(fgets(buffer, 81, input) != NULL) {
```

Since you are accessing `buffer` out of bounds, your program is subject to undefined behavior. You can fix that by making sure you that you use `B` instead of `81` in the call to `fgets()`. If you want to be able to read `81` characters at a time into `buffer`, set the value of `B` to `81`.

```
int B = 81; // 81 instead of 21

...

char buffer[B];

...

while(fgets(buffer, B, input) != NULL) { // B instead of 81
```